# Access a parent component's method from <ng-content> in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, smartadmin

Hi i am using an template for build my web app and in my template i'm using a component for datatable inside another component. I am sending a data as JSON to this component and it creates rows. I wanna CRUD with any row so i send a button html tag as json to this component end it create a button for me but the button's angular tags didn't work in my opinion it try to find my method inside the datatable component but the methods are in the main component.

**generated button html from json** : -- onClick is work but i don't want do this with javascript i prefer typescript.

```
<button class='"+buttonClass+"' (click)='remove()' ></button>
```

**component.html**

http://codepad.org/jVkRWBMV

**component.ts**

http://codepad.org/DwHK730F